# Gradle execute Groovy script in GroovyShell with Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport` when executing a gradle task, which uses `Grapes` to resolve dependencies.

I am using **Eclipse Luna 4.4.0** with a **Gradle/Groovy Project** having this **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = "de.my.app.package.Main"
version = 0.5

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ivy', name:'ivy', version:'2.2.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.2'
}

task myTask << {
    def groovyShell = new GroovyShell()
    groovyShell.run(file('/src/scripts/groovy/de/my/app/package/scripts/SomeScript.groovy'))
}
classes.finalizedBy(myTask)
```

My `Java Build Path` inside `Project->Properties` looks like this:
[image]

This is `SomeScript.groovy` inside the Folder `/src/scripts/groovy/de/my/app/package/scripts`:

```
package de.my.app.package.scripts
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1', module='org.apache.commons.codec', version='1.3.0')
)
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='commons-io', module='commons-io', version='2.4')
)
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex
println Hex.toString()
```

Weird thing is that executing `SomeScript.groovy` from `cmd` with `groovy SomeScript.groovy` does not give the error. So i am guessing it is some Eclipse config I have missed.

How can `SomeScript.groovy` be executed by the Gradle `run` from the `build.gradle` without causing a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. I needed this `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = "de.my.app.package.Main"
version = 0.5

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ivy', name:'ivy', version:'2.2.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.2'
}

task myTask (type: Exec) {
    def groovyHome = System.getenv("GROOVY_HOME")
    def someScriptPath= new String(project.projectDir.toString()).toString() + "\\src\\scripts\\groovy\\de\\my\\app\\package\\main\\SomeScript.groovy"
    commandLine  "${groovyHome}\\bin\\groovy.bat", someScriptPath
}
classes.finalizedBy(myTask)
```

So I abandoned the approach of using the class `GroovyShell`, because I could not configure the classPath for it correctly.

My Script executes now before every run. Problem is solved.